# MediaMetadataRetriever extractMetadata method returning null

Tags: android

I am using MediaMetadataRetriever class to get metadata about a video but while getting the information about the height it is returning null and for width it is returning zero.
Here is my code:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
String width =  metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH);
String height = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT);
```

Is there any other way to get width and height of a video?

Comment: did you set the datasource to your video?

Comment: yes i did it using setDataSource method. I am able to get the correct duration but not width and height.