# how do you get the artist and song title from MediaPlayer?

Tags: media-player

I'm building a simple app for an online radio station.  I using this code to use the MediaPlayer to stream the station.  It works great with one problem.  I don't know how to show the listener what they're actually listening too.
My code:

```
package com.xxxx.android;

import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Audio;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private final static String RADIO_STATION_URL = "http://";
private Button buttonPlay;
private Button buttonStopPlay;
private MediaPlayer player;
private TextView showdisplay;
private String strInfo; 

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);    

initializeUIElements();

initializeMediaPlayer();       
}    

private void initializeUIElements() {
buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);
buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(this);

buttonStopPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStopPlay);
buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false);
buttonStopPlay.setOnClickListener(this);
showdisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblDisplay);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
if (v == buttonPlay) {
    startPlaying();
} else if (v == buttonStopPlay) {
    stopPlaying();
}
}

private void startPlaying() {
buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(true);
buttonPlay.setEnabled(false);
showdisplay.setText("Buffering..");        

player.prepareAsync();

player.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        player.start(); 
    }   
});
}

private void stopPlaying() {
if (player.isPlaying()) {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
    initializeMediaPlayer();
}

buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
buttonStopPlay.setEnabled(false); 
}

private void initializeMediaPlayer() {
player = new MediaPlayer();
try {
    player.setDataSource(RADIO_STATION_URL);
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

player.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {

    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
       Log.i("Buffering", "" + percent);
    }
});       
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
if (player.isPlaying()) {
    player.stop();
}
}
```

How...specifically..and in great detail...do I update the Textview "showdisplay" with the artist and song title coming down from the radio stream in MediaPlayer?

Thanks

Comment: I used this and it worked well.
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/15828898/3999469](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15828898/3999469)

Answer (score 11):

Quick research tells me that `android.media.MediaPlayer` only cares about stream data and nothing else. Therefore, if you want to also retrieve the stream's metadata (the station name, artist, song, etc.), you must do it separately, using a different object.

The `android.media.MediaMetadataRetreiver` class seems to be built to do exactly that. It looks like you should research the `MetadataRetreiver.extractMetadata()` function along with the `METADATA_KEY_ARTIST` and `METADATA_KEY_TITLE` keys.

Here is [the MediaMetadataRetreiver API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html). Also, look at [this previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638251/how-retrieve-metadata-from-shoutcast-on-android).

I am not an Android developer so I cannot guarentee my code is correct but I think it looks something like this:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
metaRetreiver.setDataSource(RADIO_STATION_URL)
String artist =  metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
String title = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

(Full disclosure: code modified from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10385178/mediametadataretriever-extractmetadata-method-returning-null))

Comment: no one knows how to do this?  it's a piece of cake to get the MediaPlayer to actually stream a shoutcast server but no know knows a method for display the artist/song from that stream?

Comment: @user1446579 I edited my response to include a code snippet. However, I feel like you didn't even check the links I included before commenting. You did not tell me what you've done to solve the problem nor why my solution won't work. I feel like you want SO to write the code for you and that's not cool.

Comment: FYI -- tried to edit the code to fix the type and missing end parenthesis in the code sample, but the board software rejects edits that aren't more than 6 characters. :(

Comment: Fixed. Thank you.