# MediaMetadataRetriever on streaming source

Tags: android, media-player, metadata

I am having a tough time displaying the current track playing from a streaming source. Using MediaMetaDataRetriever class returns a NULL, meaning it failed. I wrote a simple method but now I'm inclining to think this only works on media files like MP3, WMA, AVI, etc.

```
public void metaData(){
        mmr.setDataSource(urlStation);
        String metaD = mmr.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ALBUMARTIST);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Artist = " + metaD, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Any good and easy recommandations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

MediaMetadataRetriever doesn't work with URL's on certain versions of Android, see [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35794) issue. I created [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever) as a workaround, I suggest trying it out.

Comment: Thanks William for your answer. This should help solve my problem.

Comment: It's only for media files, not for streaming source.

Comment: William Seemann Is it working on youtube videos.. i try it but i got metadata could not retrived error...

Comment: What URL are you using?

Comment: @William Seemann I just try to set http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mIMFL9wRaJE format is not working. after i convert to rtsp format. now its working Thank you..

Comment: That's because the URL you posted isn't a link to the actual video, it's a link to the page hosting the video.

Comment: Unfortunately that library is not working now. it is throwing `setDataSource failed: status = 0xFFFFFFFF` which is not resolved. is their any alternative solution.

Comment: @VikasAcharya, is right the library isn't working, is there any other alternative ?

Answer (score 10):

According to the same [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35794) listed in the other answer, you just need to use the setDataSource method with these arguments:

```
setDataSource(String uri, Map<String, String> headers)
```

So for example,

```
public void getStreamMetaData(String url){
  MediaMetadataRetriever mmr = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
  mmr.setDataSource(url, new HashMap<String, String>());
  //now do whatever you want

}
```

I tested it with a streaming mp4 and it worked for me. Also just a note, you'll want to use the setDataSource method in an AsyncTask or on another thread, since it may take a while to run according to the docs.

Comment: For me in that case all returned strings are null... but vlc gets info fine.

Comment: but taking time.

Comment: Works great for me in Android 9 using Kotlin: `retriever.setDataSource(videoUrl, hashMapOf())`

Comment: @rjr-apps do you have code examples I could see of how you got this working please?

Comment: @Martin - the only example I can really give is already in that comment. Are you trying that without success?

Comment: @rjr-appsI think my desired use is different from this, I'm trying to use .setDataSource on the currently playing music app (either streaming [spotify/soundcloud] or fileplayer apps), and it seems like setDataSource is only for urls and filepaths so I'm not sure It works for what I'm trying to do

Comment: is it working form hls(.m3u8) ? unknown data source exception occurred

Answer (score 2):

This method works better:

```
public void setDataSource (String uri, Map<String, String> headers)
```

(with the url of your stream and an empty map e.g
setDataSource("https://somewebsite.com/somefile.mp3", `new HashMap<String,String>()`);)