# How to get the music details of a song from its uri using media store

Tags: android, arraylist, string-comparison, mediastore

First of all, I can get all the song and its details. All I am trying is to get the song details from the URL as I can get the only URL from file navigation this is what I am trying

```
 public ArrayList<Songfileinfo> getPlayList(Context context, String uri) {
    {

        String sortOrder = null;
        try {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID
            };

            String selection = null;

            String[] selectionArgs = {uri};


            Cursor audioCursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

            if (audioCursor != null) {
                if (audioCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        int audioTitle = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);
                        int audioartist = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);
                        int audioduration = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);
                        int audiodata = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
                        int audioalbum = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
                        int audioalbumid = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
                        int song_id = audioCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);


                            Songfileinfo info = new Songfileinfo();
                            info.setFile_uri(audioCursor.getString(audiodata));
                            info.setTitle(audioCursor.getString(audioTitle));
                            info.setDuration((audioCursor.getString(audioduration)));
                            info.setArtist(audioCursor.getString(audioartist));
                            info.setAlbum(audioCursor.getString(audioalbum));
                            info.setId(audioCursor.getLong(song_id));
                            info.setAlbum_art((ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri, audioCursor.getLong(audioalbumid))).toString());
                            songList.add(info);


                    } while (audioCursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }
            assert audioCursor != null;
            audioCursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    return songList;
}
```

This is the method I am trying to use it is not working I am getting the array-list size as 0 I also tried to compare the string file location from the list of all the locations but still the array size is 0. I don't want to use media meta data retrieve as I will not get the album art URL. Any hint about how to get the details of this particular location?
I tried this way also but same result by comparing the file URI string

```
if (audioCursor.getString(audiodata).equals(uri)){
```

}
I tried to use the media metadata retriever class but it will just will not give the image url and it will be in bitmap and as my whole app is using the image url it will be difficult for me.

Comment: which format file? MP3, MP4, FLV. 
or do you want to create a generic method?

Comment: I converted the uri into string so it will compare all format mostly all are audi songs

Comment: I have the method through which i can get all the song . but i want to get the details of the song which i am passing the file location

Comment: which version of SDK are you using in your project, Can you add this information in your post? So I can give you an answer.

Comment: that is not the issue bro but for you convenience its sdk version is 25

Comment: I was working in Lolipop and never retrieved me the audio metadata, and I was reading the differents bytes per each format files, it is pretty easy. If you want to do it, just let me know.

Comment: bro as I said i am able to retrieve all the data all i want is to find the details by comparing of some other way

Comment: Sorry, I was confused, let me confirm... Do you need to get the songs details from a StreamFile?

Comment: yes bro thats what i want sorry if i confused you

Comment: I am getting only 1 file uri so I can only get the details of one song

Comment: OK in my experience I have not found a library that can read this metadata from the Url, only when you have a file locally, as I mentioned before I retrieve the metadata reading the bytes into the file depending on the file format. Now Do I explained?

Comment: are you using mediametadata Retriver class for that ??

Comment: Nope, I will post an answer for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MediaMetadataRetriever on streaming source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514321/mediametadataretriever-on-streaming-source)

Answer (score 1):

I just give this to get all the data from the url

```
  if (new File(audioCursor.getString(audiodata)).getName().equals(url.getName())) {


                            Songfileinfo info = new Songfileinfo();
                            info.setFile_uri(audioCursor.getString(audiodata));
                            info.setTitle(audioCursor.getString(audioTitle));
                            info.setDuration((audioCursor.getString(audioduration)));
                            info.setArtist(audioCursor.getString(audioartist));
                            info.setAlbum(audioCursor.getString(audioalbum));
                            info.setId(audioCursor.getLong(song_id));
                            info.setAlbum_art((ContentUris.withAppendedId(albumArtUri, audioCursor.getLong(audioalbumid))).toString());


                            songList.add(info);
                        }
```