# IllegalArgumentException on MediaMetaDataReceiver.setDataSource Android

Tags: java, android, illegalargumentexception

I want to get the song title and name when streaming from "http://usa8-vn.mixstream.net:8138". The stream is work but I don't know why when I want to get song title with MediaMetaDataReceiver, it always says IllegalArgumentException. I already using this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/10973324/2565280 but somehow it doesn't work for me.

```
MediaMetadataRetriever metaRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
metaRetreiver.setDataSource("http://usa8-vn.mixstream.net:8138");
String artist =  metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_ARTIST);
String title = metaRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_TITLE);
```

It's always error in line 2 and says IllegalArgumentException, but when I use the link for MediaPlayer it works like this

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://usa8-vn.mixstream.net:8138");
```

Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if I'm not mistaken there was a bug related to MediaMetadataRetriever.

you could try and see if:

```
metaRetreiver.setDataSource("http://usa8-vn.mixstream.net:8138", new HashMap<String, String>());
```

fixes your problem.

Comment: yep it doesnt error now, sorry for bad english. But why its always says null in METADATA_KEY_ARTIST and null in METADATA_KEY_TITLE. I checkd in current song and its not null but when i extractMetaData it says null ... did u get it ?

Comment: HashMap should contain the headers. put something inside and try again.
don't forget to accept answer :)

Comment: what kind of headers ?? pls give me example thanxx